# How to query the date in (DD/MM/YY) format

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Every item stored in my collection has a `createdAt` attribute. I want to query the date in `January 24, 2015` format. but when i use `{{item.createdAt}}` i get the date in this format `Thu Aug 11 2016 22:19:39 GMT+0800 (MYT)`.

Is it possible to get only the name of the month along with the day and the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `momentjs` package for this. Define a universal helper for the it and sue it across the project.
e.g.

```
Template.registerHelper('dateFormat', function(context) {
    if (window.moment) {
        var f = "MM DD YY";
        return moment(context).format(f); //had to remove Date(context)
    }else{
        return context;   //  moment plugin not available. return data as is.
    };
});
```

When required to format the date, call the function in template using-
`{{dateFormat item.createdAt}}` and the date will be formatted.

To add moment package use `meteor add momentjs:moment`

Comment: thanks it working and I accepted your answer, but is it possible instead of displaying the month by its name? instead of (08) i want to display Aug :)

Answer (score 0):

option 1: control what goes into your collection.
when saving the document you can specify the format of the date instead of simply using the default ISO date you can specify a format such as `new Date("<YYYY-mm-dd>")`

option 2: use $dateToString to return the date as a formatted string

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project: {
          yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } }
       }
     }
   ]
)
```

you can learn more about various formatting options available at - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/

option 3: (though you havent specified which programming language you are using)
if i assume you are using node.js then you can read the ISO date from mongodb as-is and then convert it to specific format : `dateObject.toLocaleDateString('en-US')` where dataObject is your variable that stores the returned date from the collection.